# Bluring BODY element except div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I'm trying to blur all elements in BODY, except specific div.

So, I'm made this class (CSS + LESS):

```
.blur {

    *, a.blur, a.blur:hover, a.blur:focus, h1 {
        color: transparent !important;
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    img {
        -webkit-filter: blur(3px) !important;
        -moz-filter: blur(3px) !important;
        -o-filter: blur(3px) !important;
        -ms-filter: blur(3px) !important;
        filter: blur(3px) !important;
    }

    div {
        opacity: 0.7 !important;
    }
}
```

This class blurring all the elements on body, when calling this js code:

```
$("body").addClass("blur");
```

My problem that I'm want that a specific div ("#dont-blur-this") , and all it's children (recursively) won't be effected from this class. So, it's won't be blur.

Is this possible? Do you have any tricky solution for this case?

Comment: using `!important` everywhere isn't a good practice. You should be able to manage without it + the code you share should blur only the images contained in `body.blur` (maybe you only have images though). you should share your *HTML* markup too and a fiddle would be great

Answer (score 2):

There's the `:not(#dont-blur-me-bro)` option, but you'll need to be careful with the selection. Alternatively, you could use `!important` later in the cascade to reset against earlier blur properties.